# strange result in simple arithmetic using eclipse (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, math, floating-point

When i want to calculate

> 0.9623 - 0.9619

it returns:

> 4.0000000000006697E-4

Why is that? and how can i avoid this?
I tried casting to float but didn't helped.

> ```
>   System.out.println(0.9623 - 0.9619);
> ```

prints to console:

> 4.0000000000006697E-4

Comment: Because not all decimals can be represented in binary. The 6697 at the end is the error.

Comment: [Compulsory link](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints the correct answer. `4.0000000000006697E-4` is `4.0000000000006697 * 10^(-4)` which is `0.0004`, your expected answer.

You could use `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");` to make the compiler show just four decimal places. [Here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/297-java-program-format-double-value-2-decimal-places.html) is a good example

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

You are returning a `double` in scientific notation. 
The `println` method in this case will print out the equivalent of `String.valueOf(yourDoubleValue)`

Real literals are implicitly interpreted as primitive `double`s unless specified otherwise.

To force interpretation to `float` you need to append `f` to your literals, although it won't change the fact that your result will be printed in scientific notation and with possible loss of precision:

```
System.out.println(0.9623f - 0.9619f);
```

**Output**

```
4.0000677E-4
```

I suspect what you ultimately want to print is:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.9623").subtract(new BigDecimal("0.9619")).toPlainString());
```

**Output**

```
0.0004
```

More on `BigDecimal` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your code but if decimals are important in your case, I would consider using BigDecimal especially if it's for financial apps. You can configure the rounding mode and have a better precision.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.printf("%.4f",0.9623 - 0.9619);` which will print the number with 4 decimal places. BigDecimal does tend to be overkill, and has a significant time penalty if you are doing a lot of mathematical calculations.